# Purge print jobs older than say 30 days

Tags: printing

Is there something like this in Ubuntu, or a way to immediately delete jobs after print succeeded?

Comment: They are deleted without any effort, if they succeed.

Comment: No sir, I checked the "Task options" settings, for both my 2 printers there is an option called More/"Keep until" (translated) set to "Do not keep", but the 2 queues are filled with old jobs: I checked with "Show queue" then click the green check box.

Comment: That means that it is something wrong with your system and|or printer drivers. I do not confirm it.

Answer (score 0):

And I had http://localhost:631/admin/?ADVANCEDSETTINGS=YES set to 1d (I suppose this means 1 day) not working. I set it to "Don't keep history" and now the jobs seem cleared immediately.